# ¿Porque obtengo cadenas de texto de numeros en vez de una cadena filtrada?

Tags: php, linux

Datos importantes:

- SO: Kali-linux-x86-64
- Servidor: lampp apache
- version de php: 7.2.26
- script de correos que uso: ssmtp y sendmail
- Envio hacia: hotmail (live)

Yo ya tengo configurado esto de aquí y hace poco logre hacer atravez un archivo php que se enviase un correo electronico, sin embargo antes de poder darme cuenta del porque no me estaba funcionando, tarde casi 1 dia entero en darme cuenta el porque, y fue culpa mía por no mirar que contenido se estaba enviando desde las variables de php hacia el script de sendmail.

Lo que tengo es un simple archivo en php que atravez de un formulario recibe ciertos datos con ajax y los trata para luego enviar el correo por medio de la función mail de php:

```
<?php

    header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8");

    $resultado = ["resultado" => false];

    $name = 'Nombre';
    $email = 'correo@correo.com';
    $subject = 'Hola mundo!';
    $message = 'Hola mundo desde el formulario!';
    $terms = true;

    //$name = $_POST['name'];
    //$email = $_POST['email'];
    //$subject = $_POST['subject'];
    //$message = $_POST['message'];
    //$terms = $_POST['terms'];

    if($name && $email && $subject && $message && $terms){

        //Treating data...
        $name = trim($name);
        $name = htmlspecialchars($name);
        $name = stripcslashes($name);
        $name = filter_var(FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

        $email = trim($email);
        $email = filter_var(FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
        $email = filter_var(FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);

        $subject = trim($subject);
        $subject = htmlspecialchars($subject);
        $subject = filter_var(FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

        $message = trim($subject);
        $message = htmlspecialchars($subject);
        $message = filter_var(FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

        $terms = filter_var(FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN);


        $mailHeaders = "From: $name<$email>" . "\r\n" . 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

        //Sending the email...
        $resultadoCorreoEnviado = mail($email, $subject, $message, $mailHeaders);
        $resultado["resultado"] = $resultadoCorreoEnviado;

        if (!$resultadoCorreoEnviado) {
            $errorMessage = error_get_last()['message'];
            $resultado["error"] = $errorMessage;
            $resultado["name"] = $name;
            $resultado["email"] = $email;
            $resultado["subject"] = $subject;
            $resultado["message"] = $message;
        }

    }

    echo json_encode($resultado);

?>
```

Como veis, comente la parte 'dinamica' donde recibo los datos apartir del formulario para hacer pruebas del porque no me funcionaba, y al imprimir las variables despues de ser tratadas me di cuenta de lo siguiente:

Los valores que me trae son los siguientes:

```
{
    "resultado":false,
    "error":null,
    "name":"513",
    "email":"274",
    "subject":"513",
    "message":"513"
}
```

Esto de que me traiga y envie estos valores al hacer mail(), lo solucione de una manera muy sencilla y es quitando el tratado y saneamiento de datos que le estoy haciendo a las variables.

Esto me hace cuestionarme... ¿habrá algo que estoy haciendo mal con las funciones de saneamiento y filtrado que no estoy viendo?, ¿o será por el encoding...?, ¿Qué es lo que estoy haciendo mal?, ya que yo considero que es muy inseguro simplemente no usar estas funciones y botar la seguridad por la ventana.

¿A qúe se debe esto y como puedo arreglarlo sin afectar mucho a la seguridad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema era bastante sencillo, lo que pasa es que la función `filter_var` necesita 2 parametros:

```
filter_var(variable, filtroOSaneamientoAUsar);
```

Esta función no da errores ya que el segundo parametro es opcional, esto debido a que si no se lo pasamos entonces toma como por defecto el equivalente a no realizar ningun filtro.

Yo estaba aplicando filtros y saneamiento a al filtro en sí, y no a una variable, ese era el inconveniente, que me había olvidado de incluir la variable:

```
//Treating data...
$name = trim($name);
$name = htmlspecialchars($name);
$name = stripcslashes($name);
$name = filter_var($name, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

$email = trim($email);
$email = filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
$email = filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);

$subject = trim($subject);
$subject = htmlspecialchars($subject);
$subject = filter_var($subject, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

$message = trim($message);
$message = htmlspecialchars($message);
$message = filter_var($message, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

$terms = filter_var(FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN);
```